# gulp.dest() does not result in file updates

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

Given the following dir structure:

```
<project>
 |- src
 |- gen
 |- target
```

We have a Gulp build chain in place which performs the entire front-end build for us. Intermediate results are put in the *gen* directory and the final results are put in the *target* directory.

During development, we want to monitor the *target* directory and synchronize changes to a separate directory that contains our Grails based application. We use the following snippet for this:

```
'use strict';

var debug         = require('gulp-debug');
var config        = require('../config');
var gulp          = require('gulp');
var watch         = require('gulp-watch');

module.exports = {
  //command: 'prod',
  //desc: 'Builds "production" version',
  run: function(){
     gulp.task('watch', ['server'], function() {

        // Copy files from the 'target' directory to the framework directory while developing
        var source = config.dist.root,
           destination = config.fw.root;

        gulp.src(source + '/**/*', {base: source})
           .pipe(debug({title: 'unicorn:'}))
           .pipe(watch(source + '/**/*', {base: source}))
           .pipe(debug({title: 'minotaur:'}))
           .pipe(gulp.dest(destination))
           .pipe(debug({title: 'centaur:'}));

     });
  }
};
```

When I update a source file, the build chain fires and puts the updated results in the *target* directory. But the updates are NOT synced to separate Grails directory. When I check the logging, I see this:

```
[14:29:42] Rebundle...
[14:29:42] minotaur: target\web-app\portal\js\appLoader.js
[14:29:43] minotaur: target\web-app\portal\js\appLoader.js
```

It seems that the file IS regenerated in the *target* directory and the regeneration IS picked up by the gulp-watch package. But the file is NOT written by the gulp.dest() function?!

What's might be going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, it seems that you cannot use `watch()` in the middle of your pipeline. Instead, you should use it as the head of your pipeline (instead of `gulp.src()`). Splitting the single pipeline into two separate pipelines solved the issue.

So this (removed `debug()` statements for brevity):

```
gulp.src(source + '/**/*', {base: source})
       .pipe(watch(source + '/**/*', {base: source}))
       .pipe(gulp.dest(destination));
```

Becomes this:

```
gulp.src(source + '/**/*', {base: source})
       .pipe(gulp.dest(destination));

watch(source + '/**/*', {base: source})
       .pipe(gulp.dest(destination));
```